# Error using Selenium JS Chrome Webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, npm

I like to use Selenium chromewebdriver for testing an application.

I started with this Tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Getting_Started

I downloaded newest `webdriver` and added it to path, then I tried to execute the sample code you see under getting started. I added the code to a script and tried to execute it with `> node script.js` and got the following error message:

```
undefined:1178
vlog(2, () => this + ' scheduling notifications', this);
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1123:19)
at Object.goog.loadModule (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1085:46)
at C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1:6
at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\_base.js:135:8)
at <anonymous>:1:6
at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\_base.js:104:12)
at Object.goog.importScript_ (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:879:9)
at Object.goog.importModule_ (C:\nodescripts\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:900:14)
```

Comment: we have since migrated our documentation [to GitHub](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#getting-started).   try again using the updated documentation and see if it works for you.  really not sure if there's much difference, but worth a try

Comment: thanks i tryed it like in the updated documantation but still have the same error. I tried out when the error happen, it happens when i try to require webdriver: test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing')...

Comment: sorry - i'm not too familiar with the js bindings.  you may want to [raise an issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/new)  but you will want to read the [requirements](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/tree/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#bug-reports).

Comment: I've logged this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1286

Answer (score 10):

There is a bug @version 2.48.0. I tried both on win and on linux and saw the same error message. Try using version 2.47.0.

```
npm install selenium-webdriver@2.47.0
```

Update: Update your node.js.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/

Comment: This worked for me. My error message was "undefined:1190 vlog(2, () => this + ' scheduling notifications', this)"

Comment: Better to update node.js as OlliS suggested. v5.0.0 node works fine for me after i got this error line 1190 initially

Answer (score 6):

For those who get this error and want to use the newer selenium-webdriver version:

Try updating your Node.js version.
I was getting the same error -> after updating to v4.2.2 this error does not occur anymore.

Answer (score 6):

According to pull request 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/2736

I've updated protractor and it worked for me.

```
npm install -g protractor@2

webdriver-manager update --standalone
```

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful

Comment: This solved it for me. First run "npm uninstall -g protractor" and then "npm install -g protractor@2". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well.  On selenium-webdriver's site, they state that if you are using the 12.x line of node, you must use the --harmony flag.  Doing so solved the problem for me.