# protractor step0 can't run

Tags: node.js, protractor

**I flowed this tutorial** [protractor tutrial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)

**my evirement is below**:

```html
➜  ho git:(master) ✗ nvm ls
->      v0.12.4
node -> stable (-> v0.12.4) (default)
stable -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.4) (default)
iojs -> iojs- (-> N/A) (default)
➜  ho git:(master) ✗ npm --version
2.10.1
➜  ho git:(master) ✗ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

**The** http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html **is ok**.

**When i run protractor conf.js,the result as below:**

```
➜  ho git:(master) ✗ protractor conf.js
```

[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
undefined:1190
    vlog(2, () => this + ' scheduling notifications', this);
             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
    at Object.goog.loadModule (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
    at /home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1:6
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
    at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:135:8)
    at :1:6
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:64:17)
    at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/*base.js:104:12)
    at Object.goog.importScript* (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:879:9)
    at Object.goog.importModule_ (/home/raphael/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:900:14)

**I have ever run the test code successfully.It is the new time,should i change the node version to resolve problem?Have the protractor upgraded?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using Selenium js chrome Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433914/error-using-selenium-js-chrome-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, update your Node. [Protractor 3.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/1a8bb5357ccc254ce9453972fee8521efbeb0a4d/CHANGELOG.md) had a breaking change, requiring Node 4.2. or greater.

> BREAKING CHANGE: 1) Users will no longer be able to use node versions
>   <4. 2) There is significant changes to the control flow, and tests may
>   need to be modified to be compliant with the new control flow. See
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md